# Fatal error when retrieving multiple rows with gorm Find()

Tags: go, graphql, go-gorm

I'm stuck with an obvious operation: retrieving multiple rows using gorm.Find() method.

```
(resolver.go)

package resolver

type Root struct {
    DB *gorm.DB
}

func (r *Root) Users(ctx context.Context) (*[]*UserResolver, error) {
    var userRxs []*UserResolver
    var users []model.User

    // debug-start
    // This is to prove r.DB is allocated and working
    // It will print {2 alice@mail.com} in the console
    var user model.User
    r.DB.Find(&user)
    log.Println(user)
    // debug-end

    if err := r.DB.Find(&users); err != nil { // <-- not working
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for _, user := range users {
        userRxs = append(userRxs, &UserResolver{user})
        log.Println(user)
    }

    return &userRxs, nil
}
```

```
(model.go)

package model

type User struct {
    ID    graphql.ID `gorm:"primary_key"`
    Email string     `gorm:"unique;not null"`
}
```

The mysql table is filled with 2 values. Here is the content in json style:

```
{
  { Email: bob@mail.com },
  { Email: alice@mail.com },
}
```

This is the result when I run the program:

```
2020/05/13 12:23:17 Listening for requests on :8000
2020/05/13 12:23:22 {2 alice@mail.com}
2020/05/13 12:23:22 &{{{0 0} 0 0 0 0} 0xc0004cee40 <nil> 2 0xc00031e3c0 false 0 {0xc00035bea0} 0xc0004b3080 {{0 0} {<nil>} map[] 0} 0xc000408340 <nil> 0xc0004cee60 false <nil>}
```

What is wrong with my code? It seems from all the tuto/so/etc.. sources that I'm correctly defining a slice var and passing it to the Find() function..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if err := r.DB.Find(&users); err != nil { // <-- not working
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Probably you forgot to mention Error property and returned object in this case is not nil for sure (please mention that Find returns not error interface in this case)

Please try something like that

```
if err := r.DB.Find(&users).Error; err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: It works flawlessly, thank you! Could you please point me a ressource to understand how this ".Error" works? Is it part of the standard go library? Is there another way to handle errors in gorm perhaps?

Comment: https://gorm.io/docs/error_handling.html
Thanks for pointing the solution, I'll make sure I read the docs on these topics!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a slice of **pointers**:

```
users := make([]*model.User, 0, 2)
if err := r.DB.Find(&users).Error; err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```